# Fibrations over contractible spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration

- A fibration $\pi : E \to B$ over a contractible space is fiber-homotopy equivalent to the trivial fibration $B \times \pi^{-1}(b)$ for any point $b \in B$.
- A fiber bundle over a paracompact space is a fibration.
- A fiber bundle over a paracompact contractible space is trivial: the total space is *homeomorphic* to the product of the fiber and the base.

**Question:** If $\pi:E \to B$ is a fibration over a paracompact contractible space, must $E$ be homeomorphic to $B \times \pi^{-1}(b)$? (As opposed to just being homotopy equivalent, which doesn't need paracompactness.)

Comment: Let $T$ be a right triangle and let $L$ be one of its legs. Orthogonal projection of $T$ onto $L$ is a fibration. The fiber over the endpoint of $L$ away from the right angle is a point. All the other fibers are closed intervals. Note, $L$ is contractible.